# How to set maxlength for my texteditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to set the maximum length of character for my texteditor. Users will enter text in Iframe in the editor. I am getting the characters through the `keydown` event.
I get the "maxlength" by calculating length with text & maxlength and by setting keyflag as false.

My problem is that I now have to allow the user to edit text when user press backspace, delete, ctrl+special keys.

Is there any other general ways to achieve the maxlength property?

Comment: is your texteditor a textarea? In that case there is a maxlength attribute

Comment: no i used the iframe... not textarea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dudes finally i done it..

On keyDown event and using keycodes we can achieve these functions...

```
keydown(e)
{
 if(e.keyCode==8) //for backspace key
{
 // your code
}
}
```

like wise we can write our required functions

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows once it reaches to max limit

```
var text = $('#editor').text().substring(0,maxlength);
```

text you can add to your editor as a value